# Why does visual studio not protect applications?

Tags: obfuscation

I'm just wondering.. you always have to obfuscate code these days or else everything is easily stolen by anyone with a simple drag and drop. But why doesn't  visual studio protect them in the first place? Wouldn't it be much easier for people?

Comment: "*you always have to obfuscate code these days or else everything is easily stolen by anyone with a simple drag and drop.*" - what do you mean exactly? "*But why doesn't visual studio protect them in the first place?*" - what kind of protection are you looking for exactly? Just encrypt your hard drive, and stop leaving your computer unlocked when it is unattended.

Comment: Security through Obscurification is extremely frowned upon. You do not and should not secure anything by just making it harder to understand. Visual Studios is a IDE and with proper coding techniques and understanding the roles, permission and type of security you want, you can completely avoid obscurification

Comment: No, i mean like with wpf, sorry i was unclear. There are programs like dnspy & .NET reflector that easily decompile applications and allow you to save them as a .sln so anyone can access all the code inside the application. I was asking why visual studio isn't doing anything to stop it..

Comment: Again you should not be hiding secrets directly in code. No matter what the language is.

Comment: Alrighty, you cleared up obfuscation for me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, Visual Studio does include a free obfuscation tool, [Dotfuscator Community](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/dotfuscator/?view=vs-2017). You can [install the built-in version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/dotfuscator/install?view=vs-2017) via a Quick Launch (Ctrl+Q) search for "Dotfuscator", or [download the most recent update](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads) from PreEmptive Solutions.

Full disclosure: I work for the company that makes Dotfuscator.